# Somar valores de uma string php

Tags: php

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
foreach ($class->ListaChave($CdLote) as $dados) {
   var_dump($dados->getQvol());
}
```

Saída:

```
string(1) "1"

string(1) "1"

string(1) "2"

string(1) "1"
```

Eu preciso que estes valores sejam somados e que me retorne o valor dentro de uma váriavel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer a soma normalmente. Mas se quiser garantir que o retorno de `getQVol()` seja sempre inteiro, e não tiver acesso a classe para alterar, você pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
$soma = 0;
foreach ($class->ListaChave($CdLote) as $dados) {
   $soma += (int) $dados->getQvol();
}

echo $soma;
```

Comment: Ta certo, eu estava viajando e esqueci do óbvio hehehe.